# TexWorks: Find `tab` character

Tags: texworks

Is it possible to type the `tab` character in the `TexWorks` `find` window
without needing to create a `tab` character elsewhere and then copy paste it in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on the operating system it *can* be possible; it isn't on Mac OS X (no Linux box available now and no Windows at all).

Instead, use regular expressions, which is possible by checking the appropriate option

[image]

This should teach everybody about *never* using TAB in TeX files. `;-)`

Comment: Is this an answer to "typing the `tab` character" in the Find window?

Comment: Most dope. Good use of the word 'tab' as the separator for added clarity.

Comment: @Matsmath Since the OS usually intercepts TAB as “switch between fields”, it's not possible to type a TAB in the window; with regular expressions, `\t` is translated to TAB. I clarified, thanks for commenting.

Comment: Haha, hey mister - my problem wasn't my own types of tab - I was converting someone's MS Word mess to tex, and all of my monospace code was jarred since the copypasta pulled hidden tab characters with it.

Comment: @kando I sympathize with you! `;-)` So I removed the “you” from the final note.

Comment: @kando You might be interested in [How to find characters that LaTeX doesn't like](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174723/how-to-find-characters-that-latex-doesnt-like) in case there are other problematic characters that have been pulled in from Word.